# How to take off a PX4 autopilot using mavlink message?

Tags: android, dronekit-android

I follow the following link's sample code

http://android.dronekit.io/first_app.html

and when I set API VehicleApi.getApi(this.drone).arm(true);
vehicleState.isFlying() automatically becomes true.

Can anybody tell me what this problem is?

What I need is:
1. take off, land

I read from some website that the dronekit-android does not support the mode changing. If so, how should I send the mavlink message to take off and land?
So far, I can sucessfully send the mavlink message to the PX4 board.

Thanks for replying.

Thank you for replying.

BR
SeanH

Answer (score 0):

If you trace though some of the code in dronekit-android, you can see that `isFlying` is set [here](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-android/blob/8fcbdd6be5d5179924b267bb63747d1c4d2678ab/ClientLib/src/main/java/org/droidplanner/services/android/impl/core/drone/autopilot/generic/GenericMavLinkDrone.java#L699) with the code below.

```
boolean isFlying = systemStatus == MAV_STATE.MAV_STATE_ACTIVE || ...;
```

MAV_STATE_ACTIVE, defined [here](https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/mavlink/) states

> System is active and might be already airborne. Motors are engaged.

So `isFlying` doesn't mean it's airborne but just that the motors are turned on. That occurs when you call `VehicleApi.getApi(this.drone).arm(true);` because you are literally arming the vehicle at that point.

For takeoff, you want to use the ControlApi. `ControlApi.getApi(drone).takeOff(desired_altitude, listener)` and for land you need to use `VehicleApi.getApi(drone).setVehicleMode(VehicleMode.COPTER_LAND, listener)`

The sample code you're looking at is very old. I suggest you follow the [sample app](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-android/tree/master/samples/StarterApp/src/main/java/org/droidplanner/sample/hellodrone) from github.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried android-dronekit before and I noticed that the **src** folder have not been updated for more than two years on [github](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-android/tree/develop/samples/StarterApp).

I advice you to use *python-dronekit* because there is a powerful library called ***pymavlink*** in python and used in *python-dronekit*. You can build hyper application if you want but first try to takeoff and land in python.